# TeXMaker auto-completion corrupted for new FIGURE command including label

Tags: cross-referencing, texmaker

I defined a new command \FIGURE, which takes all arguments for the filepath, label, short/long caption and size and then builds a figure environment for this. I.e. I also define the label for this figure within the command using argument 2 with

```
\label{fig:#2}
```

The problem hereby is, that the auto-completion for references to this figure in TeXMaker is corrupted. Meaning, if I type \ref{... it only suggests \ref{fig:#2} as reference, at it is defined in the new command.

Is there any way to teach TeXMaker to interpret this new defined command, so that he also suggests \ref{fig:dummy} as an option.

MWE below (need to provide a dummy.jpg file to compile)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Make \includegraphics command available
%------------------------------------------------------
% New command for easy figure environment
% #1 filepath
% #2 label
% #3 short caption
% #4 long caption
% #5 size
\newcommand{\FIGURE}[5]{
  \begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=#5]{#1}
    \caption[#3]{#4}
    \label{fig:#2}
  \end{figure}
}
%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
  \FIGURE{dummy.jpg}%
         {dummy}
         {Short dummy caption}%
         {Long dummy caption}%
         {0.8\textwidth}             
  This is text referencing \ref{fig:dummy}.             
\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess it that the only thin TeXMaker is doing is looking for any `\label{...}` in the current dir. Makeing shortcuts like this is generally not a good idea as it makes the code a lot less readable. Consider a TM user command that will insert a figure template instead.

Comment: Since the setup is always the same for all figures, apart from the text provided for the captions, I thought it would make it MORE readable, since I see at this point there will be a figure with the known setup. Indeed TeXMaker is only looking for \label commands, but I was hoping to somehow use a way, so that TeXMaker kind of follows this command and correctly interprets the \label inside the new command

Comment: I wouldn't say that that syntax is *more* readable. Also why should I want to write long and short caption every time. What if the figure needs to be rotated, what it at this particular point `hbt!` is not a good point (and why is `p` not on that list). And you will have to know that `dummy` is translated into `fig:dummy`. For ones own docs it might be fine, but if it ends up as something that goes to others, I'd much prefer the full version.

Comment: If you absolutely want to make a command interface, why not make it key=value based instead? Then you can test for the existence of a short caption, and only use it if needed. See eg `xkeyval` and `etoolbox`, the later has some good tools to test for empty ness.

Comment: Yes you're right, it might be nothing to hand on to someone else, but I am only using it for my own document. And yes I am a lazy person, this is why I am using this interface. But maybe your idea with the TeXMaker user command to insert a template for this environment is the best way to go